# Как поменять блоки в хедере местами при адаптиве?

Tags: html, css

Как видно на скринах, нужно поменять местами вообще разные элементы в разные стороны. Как это можно удобно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно сделать используя CSS Grid Layout с помощью именованных, заранее определённых грид-областей. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Grid_template_areas

Answer (score 0):

В описанном случае лучше, наверное, будет собрать новый элемент под navbar, который будет скрыт на широком экране. Да, обычно так не делают, но в показанном примере некоторые блоки вообще перестают быть частью navbar.

А поменять местами "Москва" и "Список ссылок" можно задав поменяв им grid-column.

Что касается текстовых блоков ниже, то оба текста помещаются во flex, а кнопка выводится ниже. При уменьшении экрана, их общему flex контейнеру с flex-direction:column задается justify-content: space-between.

Comment: Да, я думал о том чтоб просто добавить его отдельно для мобилок. Но могут быть из-за этого какие-то проблемы? С точки зрения профессионализма, этики и прочего? Имеется ввиду, не будет ли это костылем?

Comment: Какой макет, такая и вёрстка, я не вижу других вариантов это собрать - любой другой вариант будет включать полную пересборку grid. Эти два элемента, очевидно, выпадают из разметки navbar. А там ещё и тень у navbar.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!